# Conditional Validation doesn't update when property changes

Tags: aurelia

How do I use conditional validation based on a property that can change?

The following validation rules will only validate if the toValidate flag is set to true.

```
ValidationRules.ensure('Email').required().when(v => v.toValidate);

get toValidate() {
    if (this.checkBox.Checked)
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So when toValidate is set to true the required() rule will be ran.

If the value of toValidate changes due to the user making a change to say a checkbox on the page the validation rule is not affected and will stay either on or off depending on what it was on first loaded.

Is there a way to allow the conditional rule to be applied on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

A validation rule will only be re-run when the property in the ensure() function changes.  If you want to re-run a validation rule (or rules) on some other change, then you can do so manually.

Run all rules:

```
this.controller.validate();
```

Run one rule:

```
this.controller.validate({ object: this.yourObject, propertyName: "Email" });
```

You can setup observers in various different ways to initiate this - that's another topic!